# Oracle APEX - automatically select a single item in a cascading popup LOV

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.2

I have two cascading popup LOVs on my page P2_LOV1 and P2_LOV2

P2_LOV2 gets populated based on a query and the value selected in P2_LOV1. What I want is if there is only one value populated in P2_LOV2, set it as a selected value. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could create an on change dynamic action with a client side condition of

```
$('#P2_LOV2 option').length == 2
```

The length may be 1 or 2, depending on if you have a null option.

If true, set the value. Again, the numeric may be 1 or 0, depending on null selection.

```
('#P2_LOV2').prop('selectedIndex', 1)
```

But if you don't have a null selection, this would automatically set to first value, right?

Comment: I added this to a dynamic action for change of the P2_LOV1 but from there $('#P2_LOV2 option').length comes up as 0

Comment: I wonder if this is down to timing. I tested the syntax separately, try after-refresh of lov2 instead of on change on lov1.

Comment: that did not work either. Length is still shown at 0